# reCAPTCHA v3 in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to get Google reCAPTCHA v3 working on an ASP.NET WebForm. The library I'm using is BitArmory.ReCaptcha (https://github.com/BitArmory/ReCaptcha) but the sample code won't compile:

```
//1. Get the client IP address in your chosen web framework
string clientIp = this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
string token = null;
string secret = "your_secret_key";

//2. Extract the `#captcha` field from the hidden HTML form in your chosen 
web framework
if( this.Request.Form.TryGetValue("captcha", out var formField) )
{
    token = formField;
} 

//3. Validate the reCAPTCHA with Google
var captchaApi = new ReCaptchaService();
var result = await captchaApi.Verify3Async(token, clientIp, secret);

if( !result.IsSuccess || result.Action != "SOME_ACTION" || result.Score < 0.5 )
{
    // The POST is not valid
    return new BadRequestResult();
}
else{
    //continue processing, everything is okay!
}
```

I get errors on this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, this.Request.Form.TryGetValue, and result.IsSuccess (etc. on result.*). The site is running .NET 4.8. Will this work on .NET Framework, or is this just for .NET Core?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it works on .NET 4.8.

You can simply use `string clientIp = this.Request.UserHostAddress;` in the first line.

The second case is where you should find you reCaptcha response (it will be located in POST payload after clicking the submit button) and get in into `token` variable.

The "result" should work normally. Also, be aware that code uses `await`, so it must be executed inside an `async` method.